# Redis loads old data, shall start clean

Tags: redis

I want to use Redis as memory only. But when I start it, it loads the content of my test run (that used just the default config, i.e. without config file).

How can I prevent it to load that stuff? (Beside deleting these files. I want to ensure by configuration that I don't mistakenly load data.)

My current configuration:

```
# Redis configuration
# - memory only
# - limited to 1 GB

loglevel warning
databases 4
maxclients 50
maxmemory 1GB
maxmemory-policy noeviction
# milliseconds
lua-time-limit 100
# microseconds
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 1000
# subscribe __keyevent@0__:expired
notify-keyspace-events Ex
# is this needed? 
appendonly no
```

Comment: Do you have any "save" entry in your config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Use a .conf file
2. Remove the .rdb file (once) prior to starting `redis-server`
3. Comment out your `save` entries; see *this comment* in the default .conf : 
    *Note: you can disable saving at all commenting all the "save" lines.*

If you want to check the runtime config, you can let redis rewrite your .conf file.
See: [`CONFIG REWRITE`](http://redis.io/commands/config-rewrite)

Diff your previous config to the rewritten one, so you can see what you're missing.

To see the actual config on a running redis-server instance, use [`CONFIG GET`](http://redis.io/commands/config-get)
Example from redis-cli:

```
127.0.0.1:14130> config get *save*
```

You can also set some config options online, see [`CONFIG SET`](http://redis.io/commands/config-set)

If you want to daemonize your test server, use [`install_server.sh`](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/utils/install_server.sh). This script has had a major overhaul in 2.8.8. I recommend you do this (if possible/permissions), since it sets up a nice structure with the .conf where it should be, according to your OS's standards. Also, you can configure the daemon to start automatically after a server reboot.

Hope this helps, TW